# Play Framework [1.2.4]:Escape HTML in view layer

Tags: playframework

I have a requirement to highlight a part of text based on certain
criteria. I am identifying the text to be highlighted in my controller
and sending the updated text (along with embedded styles) to the view
layer.

I have an object - obj, with obj.text = "Welcome. Hi Dude";

When i use ${obj.Text} in the view layer. The following is displayed
as a text...

Welcome. Hi Dude";

Instead...is there way to make the text render as a HTML, meaning just
display "Welcome.Hi Dude"?

Note: I am using groovy template

Thanks,
Karthik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [Raw extension](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/javaextensions):

```
 ${obj.text.raw()}
```

Will produce HTML that is not escaped by the groovy template